# Installing rgdal in Debian, with aptitude

Tags: debian, aptitude

I am installing rgdal in a docker container that also contains RShiny. I need some specific set of libraries for installing some packages, but also a downgraded version of the libraries for gdal. I found a solution:

```
aptitude install libgdal-dev libgdal1-dev libproj-dev libgdal1h libdap-dev
```

which offers a solution:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libdap-dev [Not Installed]                         
2)     libdapserver7 [Not Installed]                      
3)     libgdal-dev [Not Installed]                        
4)     libgdal1-dev [Not Installed]                       
5)     libgdal1h [Not Installed]
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Which will non install anything, so I answer it `n`, and the offer  a second alternative:

```
      Downgrade the following packages:                           
6)      build-essential [12.1 (now, unstable) -> 11.7 (stable)]   
7)      g++ [4:5.2.1-4 (now, unstable) -> 4:4.9.2-2 (stable)]     
8)      gcc [4:5.2.1-4 (now, unstable) -> 4:4.9.2-2 (stable)]     
9)      gfortran [4:5.2.1-4 (now, unstable) -> 4:4.9.2-2 (stable)]
10)     libstdc++6 [5.2.1-16 (now, unstable) -> 4.9.2-10 (stable)]
```

Which I accept with `y`and when it prompts again to confirm the list of the packages that will be installed I confirm again. As this is done interactively is not useful for a docker container, so my question is, How can I do this sequence programatically? Is there a way to write an aptitude script or something like that?